# How do I repeat a series of functions in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph and I'm trying to simulate node attributes that are dependent on each other and are constantly changing until some form of equilibrium occurs. However, I can't get a for loop to work with this series of commands. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_empty_graph (2) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("a", value = 1) %>%
  add_vertices(2, color = 2, "a" = 2) %>%
  add_vertices(2, color = 4, "a" = 3) %>%
  add_edges(c(1,2, 2,1, 1,5, 5,1, 1,4 ,4,1)) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("xyz", value = 3)
plot(g)

for(i in 1:3){
 V(g)$xyz = sapply(V(g), function(x) { NeighborList = neighbors(g, x) ;length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 2]) } )
 V(g)$a[V(g)$xyz==1]=2
 V(g)$a
}
```

So here I want this code to run these last 3 lines 3 times but if I do a for loop like this, absolutely nothing happens. 
Ideally I wanted it to output 3 lines which looks like this:

```
[1] 2 1 2 2 3 3

[1] 2 2 2 2 2 3

[1] 2 2 2 2 2 3
```

so I could see the changes in the attributes that occurred as a result of the nodes in the network influencing each other

Comment: Your loop repeats 3 times the same thing, the loop counter `i` is never used so each time through it nothing changes. Also, can you please edit the question with the expected output?

Comment: What did you expect this code to do, and how did you evaluate that it "did nothing"? It looks like at a minimum it is changing a vertex attribute value for xyz and 'a'.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I wanted it to change the vertex attribute of 'a' and print it out 3 times to see the change in the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a loop and in a function automatic printing is turned off. Therefore, the following does not print out anything:

```
> for (i in 1:3) {
+   i
+ }
```

and in order to print out something, you have explicitly to invoke `print` inside the loop:

```
> for (i in 1:3) {
+   print(i)
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
```

In order to get the output, in your case you just need to add `print(...)` (or similar) inside the loop:

```
> for(i in 1:3) {
+   V(g)$xyz = sapply(V(g), function(x) { NeighborList = neighbors(g, x) ;length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 2]) } )
+   V(g)$a[V(g)$xyz==1]=2
+   print(V(g)$a)
+ }
[1] 2 1 2 2 3 3
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 3
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 3
```